# Laravel push notification. How to get devices token? -fcm

Tags: laravel, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, laravel-8

I have a webview application. I wrote the project in Laravel. I want to use push notifications. But how can I get device tokens? where can I find it?

```
$push->setMessage([
       'notification' => [
               'title'=>'This is the title',
               'body'=>'This is the message',
               'sound' => 'default'
               ],
       'data' => [
               'extraPayLoad1' => 'value1',
               'extraPayLoad2' => 'value2'
               ]
       ]);
$push->setApiKey('Server-API-Key');
$push->setDevicesToken(['deviceToken1'
    ,'deviceToken2',
    'deviceToken3'
]);
```

what is deviceToken1 2 3?

I created a project in Firebase. I can get the API. But how can I find and save devices' tokens? I cannot send a notification to the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, you should use Firebase SDK in your front-end to get the device ID/token, then send it to your server/Laravel (save it in your DB for later use).
There are different ways to get the device ID based on what front-end you're using, you can refer to these documentations:

- [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#access_the_registration_token)
- [IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#access_the_registration_token)
- [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token)
- [Others](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) (C++, Unity, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much. So do you know about Laravel? My android application is webview. Do I have the opportunity to send notifications to the mobile phones of the users according to their ids? Without using firebase.

Comment: There are a lot of push notification services out there, try OneSignal for example. So far, I only use Firebase. Afaik, at least you should have the Firebase server API key, even you're using OneSignal.